# About Java 7 installation

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to install Java 7 on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. I have downloaded the package in oracle, jdk1.7.0_80, which contains all the tools in bin folder.

Here comes my question. I want to switch the version of my tools to match the tools in bin folder in jdk1.7.0_80. Like java, jar and javac, whenever there exists a tool in /usr/bin, OS will automatically map the tool to my jdk bin folder. Does anyone has idea on this?

Thanks,
Xianan

Comment: How did you install JDK? Is it just extracted as a zip or installed as a package?

Comment: The package on Oracle website can only be extracted. There is no installation step.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should install java alternatives

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac
```

If you need full JRE with the web plugin you can use

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javaws
```

You can check whats available and switch between installed java versions using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solutions works just fine! One more little question is that I wonder if there is a way to automatically change all tools in bin folder, sounds like a lazy man method.